# Infopath form flicker on lost focus of html field

Tags: forms-services

I have an custom InfoPath new form for a custom list.

The last field of my form is a rich text.

When the focus is lost on this field, the browser seems to postback the data and this make the form flicker a bit (not really a problem, it's fast).

But my problem is, because it's the last field, the users clicks on a submit button of the form. Instead of submitting, the focus is lost (in profit of the button), but as the form refresh, the click on the button is ignored. The user then have to click a second time on the button to actually submit the form.

How can I avoid this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is :

> Please go to Rich text box properties > Browser forms > Select Never on postback settings > OK > Publish again and see how it works.

As suggested [Emir Liu on technet forum](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010customization/thread/775eddeb-f60c-4e3a-b634-0ada0bb8b72b/).

This removed the postback, so the click on the button is working.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue by unchecking the "Enable enhanced Rich Text content such as tables, images and hyperlinks"

Go to Rich Text Box properties -> Display -> uncheck Enable enhanced Rich Text content such as tables, images and hyperlinks